# Problem with Solve in harmonic oscillator

Tags: equation-solving

Why is the result not `Indeterminate`?

```
Solve[x == a Cos[ω t + ϕ] /. {x -> 0, t -> 0, ϕ -> π/2}, a]
```

when the result should be

```
0/Cos[π/2]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity
>   encountered.
>
> Out:= Indeterminate

Comment: Quit the kernel and try again. I cannot reproduce your problem. Evaluating `x == a Cos[ω t + φ] /. {x -> 0, t -> 0, φ -> π/2}` simply gives `True`, and so you're effectively solving `Solve[True, a]`, which has no solution: `{{}}`.

Comment: I already did that but it's still doing the same. My result is has no solution {{}} too, but Why? if the solution is indeterminate.

Comment: What is your `$Version`?

Comment: my version is the 12.0

Comment: Again: you have the equation `0==0`, which is `True`, and you're solving it for `a`, which gives no solution because there is no information about `a` in your equation. Why do you expect `Indeterminate`?

Comment: because when it is solved manually the result is indeterminate.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need?  There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. But wait! It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 2):

When I run your code, I get:

```
Solve[x == a Cos[ω t + ϕ] /. {x -> 0, t -> 0, ϕ -> π/2}, a]
{{}}
```

As @MichaelE2 points out, this means a "full-dimensional solution" (as documented in the help file for Solve). The reason this occurs is because the equation contains

```
a Cos[ω t + ϕ] /. {x -> 0, t -> 0, ϕ -> π/2}
0
```

which evaluates to zero. So you are effectively solving

```
Solve[0 == a*0, a]
{{}}
```

which similarly returns a full dimensional solution set. In this case, since a is the variable being solved for, this may be interpreted as "true for all a".

Comment: Note: `{}` indicates an empty solution set, while `{{}}` indicates a full-dimensional component.

Comment: If we solve to variable A :
then 0  / cos 90 is equal a indeterminate, only that was my question. But I saw other result and this alarmed me.

Answer (score 1):

`ContourPlot` shows the possible solutions:

```
ContourPlot[0 == a Cos[y] , {y, 0, Pi}, {a, -1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {y, a}]
```

[image]